# Can UTF-8 encoded characters be used in a page title?

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, page-title

I would have expected that the page title respected the charset, but I'm seeing differently. Setting `document.title` to `Fo&#x27;o Bar` doesn't result in `Fo'o Bar` being printed as the page title. My browser encoding is set to UTF-8, I am declaring the charset in a meta tag, and the file is saved as UTF-8. It seems like my only option is to use JavaScript to create a DOM node and then set the `document.title` to the text from that node. Is this right?

Comment: The character, `&#x27;`, is HTML encoded, not JavaScript encoded.

Comment: actually, it's "xml" encoded as opposed to an html entity like &quot; or &apos; ...

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for the correction. I'm not sure how I missed that. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your title like this:

```
document.title = 'Fo\u0027o Bar';
```

See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Unicode_escape_sequences) for full documentation on escaping Unicode characters.

Comment: To close the loop, the cause for those HTML entities was that the title string was being generated using a Handlebars template. Handlebars was escaping those characters with HTML entities. Unfortunately, I can only suggest that we stop using a template engine that specifically targets HTML to produce a page title. In the meantime, I'll have to escape those characters with the unicode versions before or after Handlebars does its thing. Thanks for the help!